# Как правильно получить текст из буфера обмена?

Tags: c++, кодировка, clipboard

Здравствуйте!

Для получения текста из буфера используется следующий код:

```
string GetClipboardText()
{
    if (!OpenClipboard(nullptr)) 
        return "";

    HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
    if (hData == nullptr)
        return "";

    char * pszText = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hData));
    if (pszText == nullptr)
        return "";

    string text(pszText);

    GlobalUnlock(hData);
    CloseClipboard();

    return text;
}
```

Проблема такова:

Если копировать русский текст с английской раскладкой, то на выходе вместо русских букв получаются ????

Например, текст "Привет, мир!" превратится в "??????, ???!"

Знающие люди, подскажите, пожалуйста решение проблемы.

Comment: А вы пользуйтесь юникодной версией проекта, и `wchar_t*` вместо `char*`.

Comment: И CF_UNICODETEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отредактировал код, как сказали выше Mikalai Ramanovich и VladD, спасибо.

Теперь работаю с wstring и юникодом.

```
wstring GetClipboardText()
{
    if (!OpenClipboard(nullptr))
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return L"";
    }

    HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
    if (hData == nullptr)
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return L"";
    }

    wchar_t * pszText = static_cast<wchar_t*>(GlobalLock(hData));
    if (pszText == nullptr)
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return L"";
    }

    wstring text(pszText);

    GlobalUnlock(hData);
    CloseClipboard();

    return text;
}
```